# What type of plane is this wreck?

Tags: world-war-two, military, identification

[image: aircraft wreck]

I have found this picture on MSN, with the claim that it is a P-38 somewhere at the French Riviera. However the P-38 Lightning is a twin-engined fighter, while this wreck has most probably four. What is it?

Answer (score 35):

It is, in fact, a twin-engined American P38 Lightning:

[image: P38 in flight]

That particular aircraft was shot down on 27 January 27 1944. The wreck is located in  Lecques Bay at a depth of about 40 meters, about one kilometre west of Grenier Point.

The wreck was discovered in November 1996, and identified as G15-LO (serial number 43-2545) flown by 2nd Lt. Harry Greenup of 49th Squadron, 14th Fighter Group, 15th USAAF.

You can read more about it on the page [Epave de l’avion P 38 Lightning aux Lecques](http://www.lac-du-bourget.fr/epave-de-lavion-p-38-lightning-aux-lecques/).

The engines appear to be 'out of place' on the sea bed because the aircraft broke up on impact.

---

It is a popular dive site, and there are a number of videos like [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHwIOdvPl_8) of divers exploring the wreck on YouTube.

---

As an interesting aside, this map of dive sites in the vicinity shows that the wrecks of two P38 Lightnings are located in the bay:

[image: map]

Comment: Ow. Thank you. The engines seemed to lie so neatly in one line... And I even believed to see the shape of third rotor on the other side.